# How to override angular ui bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to add new type class button in my datepicker.

Example:

1. Button blue colour for range date from Jan 8, 2014 until Jan 18, 2014
2. or, button red colour for date Feb 2, 2014.

I already try to ovveride datepicker directive, but it doesn't work. Here my codes:

```
angular.module('App').directive('NewDatepickerPopup',function(){
return{
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    require: ['datepicker'],
    templateUrl: 'template/datepicker/datepicker.html',
    controller: function($scope){
        console.log('controller NewDatepickerPopup');
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, requiredControllers){
        console.log('requiredControllers',requiredControllers);
        console.log('link NewDatepickerPopup');
        element.on('click',function(){
            console.log('on click nya disini');
        });
    }
};
```

});

```
angular.module("template/datepicker/datepicker.html", []).run(["$templateCache",
function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put("template/datepicker/datepicker.html",
        "<table class=\"zor-datepicker\" >\n" +
        "  <thead>\n" +
        "    <tr>\n" +
        "      <th><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-cal btn-sm pull-left\" ng-click=\"move(-1)\"><i class=\"fa fa-angle-left fa-lg\"></i></button></th>\n" +
        "      <th colspan=\"{{rows[0].length - 2 + showWeekNumbers}}\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-cal btn-sm btn-block\" ng-click=\"toggleMode()\">{{title}}</button></th>\n" +
        "      <th><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-cal btn-sm pull-right\" ng-click=\"move(1)\"><i class=\"fa fa-angle-right fa-lg\"></i></button></th>\n" +
        "    </tr>\n" +
        "    <tr ng-show=\"labels.length > 0\" class=\"h6\">\n" +
        "      <th ng-show=\"false\" class=\"text-center ng-hide\">#</th>\n" +
        "      <th ng-repeat=\"label in labels\" class=\"text-center\">{{label}}</th>\n" +
        "    </tr>\n" +
        "  </thead>\n" +
        "  <tbody>\n" +
        "    <tr ng-repeat=\"row in rows\">\n" +
        "      <td ng-show=\"false\" class=\"text-center ng-hide\"><em>{{ getWeekNumber(row) }}</em></td>\n" +
        "      <td ng-repeat=\"dt in row\" class=\"text-center\">\n" +
        "        <button type=\"button\" style=\"width:100%;\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm\" ng-class=\"{'btn-info': dt.selected}\" ng-click=\"select(dt.date)\" ng-disabled=\"dt.disabled\"><span ng-class=\"{'text-muted': dt.secondary}\">{{dt.label}}</span></button>\n" +
        "      </td>\n" +
        "    </tr>\n" +
        "  </tbody>\n" +
        "</table>\n" +
        "");
}
```

]);

```
<input id="ph" ng-click="openCheckin($event)" name="in" type="text" class="form-control search home" new-datepicker-popup datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="check_in" ng-change="changeCheckinDate()" is-open="openedCheckin" min="minCheckInDate" ng-required="false" show-weeks="false" show-button-bar="false" close-text="Close" placeholder=""/>
```

Anybody could help me?

Thank you so much

*Sorry my english so bad.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this post: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/743
You could use decorator in the config phase to override the templateUrl